# Alfresco share "site content" (docsummary) dashlets customization

Tags: alfresco-share

There are three filters out of the box.
1. I've Recently modified,
2. I'm editing and
3 my favorite
inside site content(docsummary) dashlets alfresco share.

I need to add one more filter called "modified by other user".
Is it possible, could someone please put lights on it.

Comment: which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: Hey Krutik thanks for quick response, I am using alfresco community 4.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To modify “site content” dashlets:

you need to add `<filter type="editingOthers" />` in file `docsummary.get.config.xml`

And add `filter.editingOthers=Modified By Others` in file `docsummary.get_en.properties`

After this you may have to change web script to search desired parameter for your dashlet. For that make changes in `doclist.get.js` file located in  `alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\slingshot\documentlibrary\doclist.get.js`.

For ref: https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#Advanced_Implementations

Comment: I din't find doclist.get.js in my alfresco environment. Could you please help me.

Comment: I din't have doclist.get.js file in my alfresco environment. Is it version specific?

Comment: If you have successfully deployed alfresco than this file must be available in directory mentioned in ans.